# VBA code - Sumbycellscolor

Tags: excel, vba

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 12).Formula = "=sumcellsbycolor(K1:K" & LastRow & ",(colorindex=6))"
```

In actual formula instead of (colorindex=6) we should select the cell of which color we need. But since I do not have fixed cell to give ref.

So how can I use this color index in the above formula

Answer (score 0):

You can try this program code. You get results of sum by color in `"L1"` . Color choices are in `Range(M1:M3)`.  You have to change row number number indication in the code as indicated by me. Image given after code shows the sample data. HTH

```
Sub SumByColorV()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim result As Long
    Dim cSum As Long
    Dim ColIndex As Integer
    Dim CellColor As Range
    Dim rRange As Range
    Set CellColor = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 13) 'Vary row no 1 or 2 or 3 of column 13 (M) as per yr requirement
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(lastRow, 11))
    ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex

    For Each cl In rRange
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
        cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
        End If
    Next cl
    result = cSum
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 12).Value = result
End Sub
```

[image: Sample data with result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which can be passed two arguments, a range of cells and a variant which can either be a color index, a standard name for a color, or a 1 cell range. If it is passed a range for that argument, it sums against the color index of the range:

```
Function IndexFromName(ByVal colorName As String) As Long:
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    s = LCase(colorName)
    Select Case s
        Case "black": i = 1
        Case "white": i = 2
        Case "red": i = 3
        Case "green": i = 4
        Case "blue": i = 5
        Case "yellow": i = 6
        Case "magenta": i = 7
        Case "cyan": i = 8
        Case Else: i = -4142 'color automatic -- perhaps should return an error
    End Select
    IndexFromName = i
End Function

Function SumIfColor(R As Range, color As Variant) As Double
    'summ cells with a given color index
    'which may differ from displayed color
    'if conditional formatting is in use!
    Dim i As Long, ci As Long, s As Double, c As Range

    If TypeName(color) = "Range" Then
        ci = color.Interior.ColorIndex
    ElseIf TypeName(color) = "String" Then
        ci = IndexFromName(color)
    Else
        ci = color
    End If
    For Each c In R.Cells
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = ci Then s = s + c.Value
    Next c
    SumIfColor = s

End Function
```

It can be used directly in the spreadsheet:

[image]

In the above image I entered the formula `=SumIfColor($A$1:$H$10,A13)` in cell A14 and copied it across the nxt two columns.

The function `IndexFromName` can of course be expanded. I only implemented the 8 colors which correspond to named constants like `vbYellow`. You could, for example, determine the standard HTML color names for the other colors in the standard Excel color palette.

Note that color in Excel is now substantially more complicated than just the color index of the cell. Displayed colors are no longer limited to the palette and conditional formatting is a constant complicating factor. The only valid use case is when the only displayed colors are those explicitly selected by the user using the color palette.